# How can I validate scala syntax?

Tags: scala, syntax

I'm trying to check the syntax of my scala programs, I didn't find an option in the "scalac" compiler that would only check my code for syntax errors:

I´m using `scalac Ystop-after:parse fileName.scala` but I can't get the syntax checked

Thanks

Comment: Can you expand in your use case? Why do you only want to check for syntax?

Comment: Hi Luis, I have a notebook wrote in scala. I just want to check the scala syntax in the notebook. Thanks

Comment: You may be interested in [**mdoc**](https://github.com/scalameta/mdoc) then. It has an only compiles mode, but I guess the idea of running your snippets and saying the output in the notebook may be even better.

Comment: You can give a try to intellij idea for writing your scala programs. There just install the scala plugin and it will help you in much better way. You can create your scala worksheets to see instant output of your code or create class with main. Intellisense of intellij could be of great help.

Comment: You could also try the Official Scala Syntax extension in VS Code if you want something minimal.

Comment: In what way, exactly, does `-Ystop-after:parser` not do what you want? That's the answer I would have suggested. You might also consider `-Ystop-after:typer`.